# LINQ Lambda | Query Syntax VS Method Syntax Performance

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, linq

Dúvida em relação a construção e performance de *querys* utilizando `Query Syntax` e `Method Syntax` / `LINQ`

**Query Syntax:**

```
var VendorQuery = from v in vendors
                  where v.CompanyName.Contains("Toy")
                  orderby v.CompanyName
                  select v;
```

**Method Syntax**

```
var vendorQuery = vendors
                  .Where(v => v.CompanyName.Contains("Toy"))
                  .OrderBy(v => v.CompanyName);
```

**Obs:** As *querys* acima são fictícias, apenas para exemplificar.

> 1. Em ambas as situações a mesma query é montada?
> 2. Supondo que eu tenha que fazer uma busca relativamente "pesada", faz
>      diferença usar um ou outro?

Comment: Pelo que sei sim, em ambos os cenários o resultado é o mesmo. Em relação à consulta "pesada", depende, pesada em números de registos ou com muitos `JOIN` ou `GROUP BY`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sim é a mesma performance pro seu exemplo. E segundo a documentação:

> A maioria das consultas na documentação introdutória da LINQ (Consulta
>   Integrada à Linguagem) é escrita usando a sintaxe de consulta
>   declarativa da LINQ. No entanto, a sintaxe de consulta deve ser
>   convertida em chamadas de método para o CLR (Common Language Runtime)
>   do .NET quando o código for compilado.

Levando em consideração o especificado acima da no mesmo qual você irá utilizar desde que a lógica seja a mesma.

Pra saber sobre performance você tem que verificar a `query` gerada. Uma dica pra você conseguir observar a `query` gerada é fazer o seguinte no seu `Context`:

```
public DatabaseContext() : base("MeuContext")
{
    //Trecho abaixo utilizado para ver as querys geradas pelo Entity
    #if DEBUG
    Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);
    #endif
}
```

Esse trecho `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s)` vai fazer com que a `query` gerada aparece no Output quando você estiver debugando e te ajudará a entender melhor a geração das querys. Você pode inclusive testar o exemplo que deu aqui na pergunta pra ver se realmente gera a mesma query.

**Referência:**

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq